# How to set the Return-Path to an email address other than Sender address using JavaMail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

How to set the Return-Path to an email address other than Sender address using JavaMail?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The code below does what you want, and does it in the correct way. Reread what you yourself posted in the comment

> From: [RFC2821: 4.4 Trace Information](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)
>
> When the delivery SMTP server makes
> the "final delivery" of a message, it
> inserts a return-path line at the
> beginning of the mail data.  This use
> of return-path is required; mail
> systems MUST support it.  The
> return-path line preserves the
> information in the 
> from the MAIL command.  Here, final
> delivery means the message has left
> the SMTP environment.  Normally, this
> would mean it had been delivered to
> the destination user or an associated
> mail drop, but in some cases it may be
> further processed and transmitted by
> another mail system.

and a few lines later.

> A message-originating SMTP system
> SHOULD NOT send a message that already
> contains a Return-path header.

If you carefully read this you will understand that only the final smtp-server/delivery agent is supposed to add the `Return-Path` header. It is not something you as client (trying to send a mail) should do. The final smtp-server will base the `Return-Path` header on the sender address of the envelope (`SMTP MAIL FROM` part).

So setting `mail.smtp.from` is the correct way to tell java that the envelope sender address should be different from the `from` part.

If you have troubles understanding what the different `from`'s are just take a look at a telnet smtp-session. Where `replyto@example.com` should correspond to `mail.smtp.from` and `from@example.com` to `m.addFrom(...);`

```
telnet smtp.example.com 25 
220 smtp.example.com ESMTP .....

helo computername
250 smtp.example.com Hello computername [123.123.123.123]

mail from:<replyto@example.com>
250 <replyto@example.com> is syntactically correct

rcpt to:<rcpt@foo.com>
250 <rcpt@foo.com> verified

data
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
To: Joey <to@joey.com>
From: Joey <from@example.com> 
Subject: Joey

Hey Joey!

.
250 OK id=....

Quit
```

---

```
props.put("mail.smtp.from", "replyto@example.com");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
m.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("from@example.com"));
```

Comment: I believe it would be the solution. But from what I read, the mail server must support it.
"When the delivery SMTP server makes the "final delivery" of a message, it inserts a return-path line at the beginning of the mail data. This use of return-path is required; mail systems MUST support it. The return-path line preserves the information in the <reverse-path> from the MAIL command." in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

Comment: i have been trying to do this on many other levels of the code, this is the only solution that has worked for me

Comment: "But from what I read, the mail server must support it." who must support it ? Initial SMTP server or the one who makes the final delivery?

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced the same issue and found the only solution discussed putting property  "mail.smtp.from" props.put("mail.smtp.from", "replyto@example.com");

Still this solution was not suitable for me because I'm sending lot's of e-mails from different users, so recreating session for each e-mail would be horrible for prodictivity.

So I found another solution after reading JavaMail sources:

1) Use SMTPMessage(extends MimeMessage) instead of MimeMessage.

2) Use setEnvelopeFrom(String) method.

3) Use SMTPTransport to send e-mail (I didn't try with others).

Here is a code example:

```
SMTPMessage message = new SMTPMessage(session);
message.setEnvelopeFrom("returnpath@hotmail.com");
...
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: This worked for me when the "mail.smtp.from" method didn't. Thanks! Delightful.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the 'mail.protocol' property is set to something other than 'smtp' (like 'smtps'), then only the following would work:

```
props.put("mail.smtps.from", "replyto@example.com");
```

This allowed me to avoid using the SMTPMessage class as described in GiorgosDev's answer (classes in the 'com.sun' package aren't intended to be public API).

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: the first answer didn't work for me as-is; the second is hacky; this one worked for me (i'm using smtps instead of smtp as the 'mail.protocol')... just thought i'd share...