# Handling Bounced Emails in Java API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am sending Bulk Emails using Java API, and I would Like To have a Report of all Bounced Emails. Reading Around I found that I can Implement a Bounced Emails Address:

```
  props.put("mail.smtp.from", bounceAddr);
```

But the Emails always get Bounced back to the Original Address. Here is My relevant piece of Code:

```
String smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int port = 587;
    final String userid = "myuserid";//Source Email
    final String password = "mypassword";//Source Email
    String contentType = "text/html";
    String subject = "test: bounce an email to a different address "
            + "from the sender";
    String from = "mysourceaddress@gmail.com";
    String to = "myfakeaddress@gmail.com";//some invalid address
    String bounceAddr = "mybouncedEmailsaddress@gmail.com";//bounced Emails address
    String body = "Test: get message to bounce to a separate email address";

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.from", bounceAddr);
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userid, password);
                }
            });

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContent(body, contentType);

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending ....");
        transport.connect(smtpServer, port, userid, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        System.out.println("Sending done ...");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.err.println("Error Sending: "  + e.getMessage());
    }
    transport.close();
```

The Emails always get Bounced back to mysourceaddress@gmail.com. Is there something I am Missing or are there other Better ways to Implement this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Mail: Getting Bounced Messages To Go To An Address Different From The Sender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262251/java-mail-getting-bounced-messages-to-go-to-an-address-different-from-the-sende)

Comment: How is that Answer given different from the Post I have given. It is the same.

Comment: I have no way of knowing that since you don't show how you create/configure the MIME message.

Comment: So there is my full code and it is still bouncing back to the original mail.

Comment: Yup, looks correct. Looks like a GMail SMTP issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17789673/3558960